# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "pyopenpose" when I try to install the addon "openpose"

Tags: python, add-on

I am trying to install the addon named **"OpenPose" written by "Marie Eve Dumas" & "Emmanuel Durand"** that you can find here :

https://gitlab.com/sat-metalab/blender-addon-openpose

on blender 2.81 / Windows 10. As you can see,the addon requires the pyopenpose module,that I don't know how to enable :

[image: error addon]

The instructions for installing the **pyopenpose** module are on this site :

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/modules/python_module.md#installation

Specially here :

**"To compile, enable BUILD_PYTHON in CMake-gui, or run cmake -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON .. from your build directory. In Windows, make sure you compile the whole solution (clicking the green play button does not compile the whole solution!). You can do that by right-click on the OpenPose project solution, and clicking in Build Solution (or individually building the PyOpenPose module)."**

But I'm not able to understand what to do. But I understand that I should open **"Cmake"** and I should make some kind of setup there,but I don't know how. Below you can see the error that I get when I try to tick the **"BUILD_PYTHON"** option.

[image: error cmake]

I don't know what to do further.

NB : I have already installed Open Pose on Windows 10,following this tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC9GTb6Wsb4

and openpose works great. please help me with pyopenpose. thanks.

NB : below you can find the cmake output file :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CNsWDHpQNRqQo_3JBm8Fw_SeWn4vUp0k